# What is an efficient way to run C# Tasks in Sequence

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I'm trying to find a way to schedule Tasks to run in sequence. The solution I came up so far with is posted below, but I have a suspicion that it can be done in a much easier / more efficient way.

```
public class SequentialTaskRunner
{
    private ISet<Task> runningTasks = new HashSet<Task>();

    public void Run(Task task)
    {
        lock (runningTasks)
        {
            var tasksToAwait = runningTasks.ToArray();

            // create a task that waits for the currently running tasks
            var waitingTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                Task.WaitAll(tasksToAwait);
            });

            // make sure the task gets removed from the running tasks on completion
            task.ContinueWith((antecedent2) =>
            {
                lock (runningTasks)
                {
                    runningTasks.Remove(task);
                }
            });

            // prepend the waiting task 
            waitingTask.ContinueWith((antecedent) => task.Start());

            runningTasks.Add(task);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to use this for enqueueing tasks dealing with com-port connections, to prevent them from getting in each others way.

The situation is as follows: I'm working with an rfid device. There's 2 drivers in play. 1 for reading / writing. Another one that can scan the available com ports on request to find an(other) reader. Sometimes, a port scan will be done using the reader driver, to restore a connection. It's exactly these 2 'port scanning' tasks that I do not want to co-occur.

I hope this clarifies how I got into the situation of wanting 2 tasks not to run at the same time. Now, there may be another way out, avoiding having to answer this question. But I'm still very curious what a good solution would be :)

Comment: So, you want to run tasks synchronously?  How ever did you get yourself in this spot?  Can you back out and just use Actions?

Comment: That's a good question. I'll edit my post to elaborate on this a little.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*(Entire previous post stricken per comments)*.

My new understanding is you have 3 types of tasks.

1. Reader
2. Writer
3. Port Scanner

You'd like these three to be as parallel as possible, but you'd also like the Reader, if it so chooses to jump into a port-scanning Reconnect, to not do so while a Port Scanner is alive. One way to tackle this situation is with a [Semaphore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore.aspx). Semaphores control access to a limited number of resources.

In your case, you have a limited number (in fact just 1) of resources ("port scanning") available. In this instance we could elect to use a simpler [`AutoResetEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent.aspx). However, I feel a `Semaphore` may actually reduce confusion.

```
// Only 1 task may port scan at a time
Semaphore portScanResource = new Semaphore(initialCount: 1, maximumCount: 1);

// ...

// "Reader task"
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew( () =>
    {
        // ...
        if (shouldPortScan)
        {
            portScanResource.WaitOne();
            try
            {
                // do your port scan
            }
            finally
            {
                // we're done
                portScanResource.Release();
            }
        }
    });
```

The Port Scanner task would use the same `Semaphore`, ensuring only 1 thread executes a port scan at a time.

Comment: If I understood it well, the ConcurrentBag doesn't allow me to withdraw 'task' from the 'runningTasks'. I'm currently looking if the ConcurrentQueue can fit in as @anvarbek suggested, since the 'finishing task' should always be the one to dequeue, this may work.

Comment: @bvh: your edit makes this more clear. I'm mulling this over. If I cannot come up with a better solution I'll just delete this answer.

Comment: nice. Looking at my example code, I find the method name 'Run' a bit confusing. Alternatives would be 'Enqueue' or 'Schedule'. The latter of these suggests that making a scheduler is an interesting option too.

Comment: I will try that, it's a much more subtle way to get the 'enqueuing' behavior that's for sure.

Comment: I flagged this as the answer, since it solves my 'original' problem. Thanks for thinking along!

Comment: @bvh: you're welcome. Sometimes, especially with threading, it is hard to communicate the desired behavior :)

Answer (score 0):

if you on C# 4, you could `ConcurrentQueue` class which is thread safe for your queue

or have a look other Concurrent* classes in C4. Parallel extensions are quite handy as well, but oyu will need to tune it to yr need